# Not able to connect to IBM Bluemix with TLS1.2 Security?

Tags: embedded, bluemix

I am trying to connect a device to IBM Bluemix with TLS1.2 security with Quectel M95 GPRS Hardware.
Can any one help why I am not able to open SSL connection. I am getting QSSLOPEN command response as '-1'.

The command firing sequence is:

```
{ "ate0", "OK", 20, 2500, 0 },      
{ "at+cpin=?", "OK", 6, 6000, 0 },  
{ "at+qinistat", "+QINISTAT: 3", 25, 350, 0 },  
{ "at+creg?", "+CREG:", SIM_MAX_REG, 350, 0 },  
{ "at+clip=1","OK",5,350, 0 },              
{ "at+qaudch=2", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                         
{ "at+clvl=50", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                              
{ "at+qmic=0,14", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },
{ "ats0=0", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                                                      
{ "at+qspn?", "+QSPN:", 3, 350, 0 },                            
{ "at+cmgf=1", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                           
{ "at+cscs=\"ira\"", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                     
{ "at+csmp=49,167,0,241", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                    
{ "at+cnmi=2,1,0,1,0", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                       
{ "at+qifgcnt=0", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                     
{ "at+qimux=1", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                  
{ "at+qidnsip=", "OK", 5, 350, 5 },                 
{ "at+qicsgp=1,", "OK", 5, 350, 2 },                 
{ "at+qimode=0", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                             
{ "at+cgreg?", "+CGREG:", GPRS_MAX_REG, 350, 0 },               
{ "at+qiregapp", "OK",  5, 350, 0 },                             
{ "at+qiact", "OK", 15, 2000, 0 },                              
{ "at+qindi=1", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                              handle 
{ "at+qisde=0", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                              //21 Control  
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"ignorertctime\",1","OK",5,350, 0 },             //22    
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"sslversion\",0,4","OK",5,350, 0 },              //22 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"ciphersuite\",0,\"0X009C,0X009D\"","OK",5,350, 0 }, //23 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"seclevel\",0,1","OK",5,350, 0 },                //24 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"seclevel\",0,2","OK",5,350, 0 },                //24 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"ctxindex\",0","OK",5,350, 0 },                  //24 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"cacert\",0,\"RAM:cacert.pem\"","OK",5,350, 0 },     //25 

{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"clientcert\",0,\"RAM:client.pem\"","OK",5,350, 0 }, //26 
{ "AT+QSSLCFG=\"clientkey\",0,\"RAM:userkey.pem\"","OK",5,350, 0 }, //26 


{ "at+qsslopen=0,0,","+QSSLOPEN:",5, 35000, 3 },                //28 Start 
{ "at+qiopen=1,\"tcp\",","CONNECT",3, 1000, 4 },                //29 Start 
{ "at+qsslstate", "+QSSLSTATE:", 10, 2500, 0 },                 //30
{ "at+qsslsend", ">", 3, 1000, 1 },                             //31 Send 
{ "at+qisend", ">", 3, 1000, 1 },                               //25 Send d
{ "at+qsslrecv=0,0,512", "+QSSLRECV:", 2, 750, 0 },             //32 Read 
{ "at+qird=0,1,1,512", "+QIRD:", 2, 750, 0 },                   //33 Read 
{ "at+qiopen=0,\"tcp\",","CONNECT",5, 5000, 3 },                //22 Start 
{ "at+qiopen=1,\"tcp\",","CONNECT",3, 5000, 4 },                //23 Start 
{ "at+qistate", "STATE:", 10, 2500, 0 },                        //24
{ "at+qisend", ">", 3, 1000, 1 },                               //25 Send 
{ "at+qisend", ">", 3, 1000, 1 },                               //25 Send 
{ "at+qird=0,1,0,512", "+QIRD:", 2, 750, 0 },                   //26 Read 
{ "at+qird=0,1,1,512", "+QIRD:", 2, 750, 0 },                   //27 Read 
{ "at+qisack","+QISACK",2,1000, 0 },                            //34

{ "at+qsslclose=0","CLOSE",8,350, 0 },                          //35 Close 
{ "at+qiclose=0","CLOSE",8,350, 0 },                            //29 Close 
{ "at+qiclose=1","CLOSE",8,350, 0 },                            //36 Close  
{ "at+qccid"," ",5,350, 0 },                                    //37 Show 
{ "at+cnum","+CNUM:",3,350, 0 },                                //38    
{ "at+qilocip"," ",5,350, 0 },                                  //39 Get 
{ "ata", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                                     //40 Answer 
{ "ath", "OK", 3, 350, 0 },                                     //41 
{ "atd", "OK", 5, 350, 0 },                                     //42 
{ "at+qcellloc=1", "+QCELLLOC", 3, 2000, 0 },                   //43    
{ "at+qhttpurl=","CONNECT",10, 500, 0 },                        //44 Set 
{ "http:// ","OK",6, 500, 0 },                                  //45 Set 
{ "at+qhttpget=60","OK",3, 61000, 0 },                          //46 HTTP 
{ "at+qhttpread=60","CONNECT",3, 61000, 0 },                    //47 Read   
{ "at+ctzu=3","OK",3,350, 0 },                                  //48 Network 
{ "at+qnitz=1","OK",3,350, 0 },                                 //49 Network 
{ "at+cclk?","+CCLK:",3,350, 0 },                               //50 Clock 
{ "at+qmgda=\"del all\"","OK",4,750, 0 },                       //51 Delete 
{ "at+csq","CSQ:",3,350, 0 },                                   //52 Read 
{ "at+gsn"," ",3,350, 0 },                                      //53 Read 
{ "at+qpowd=0","OK",3,350, 0 },                                 //54 Power 
{ "at+cfun=4","OK",5,350, 0 },                                  //55 Power 

/********** SSL Connection *********/
{ "at+qsslrecv=","+QSSLRECV:",5,350, 0 },       //56 AT+QSSLRECV    Retrieve 
{ "at+qsslstate","+QSSLSTATE:",5,350, 0 },      //57 AT+QSSLSTATE   Query 
{ "at+qsecwrite=","CONNECT",3,500, 0 },         //58 AT+QSECWRITE   Add a  
{ "at+qsecread=","+QSECREAD:",3,500, 0 },       //59 AT+QSECREAD    Query      
{ "at+qsecdel=","OK",5,350, 0 },                //60 AT+QSECDEL     Delete a
```

I am firing the commands with the help of Enums for each command and trying to fire the commands in two modes:

1. With Security will fire QSSL CFG commands.
2. Without TLS1.2 Security the normal TCPIP connection without Ciphersuits will be made.

I have given the org ID, Auth username, Auth Password in code.

So please help me on this issue...

Also, If you can suggest me a good practical book explaing the concepts of coding with examples regarding IoT programming will be a great help..

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. The firing Sequence was correct and I have connected to IBM Bluemix successfully with TLS1.2 Security.